# Excel Converting rows to columns with groups

Tags: excel, pivot-table, transpose

Let's say that I have my columns in excel set up like this:

```
Name     A    B    C    D  
George   10   5    4    6
```

And I want it to instead be like this:

```
Name   Category   Amount  
George     A        10  
George     B         5  
George     C         4  
George     D         6
```

Is there an easy way to do a copy and paste with transpose, or with a pivot table, or does it have to be done with VBA? I've been trying to only do it with VBA but I havent gotten very far.

Comment: Try this tip: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/creating_a_database_table_from_a_summary_table/. You can still access the pivot table wizard in later versions of Excel by pressing `Alt-D-P`.

Comment: Thank you, do you want to post it as an answer so that I can credit you for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment, you can follow that link. A related SO answer that describes similar steps for Excel 2010 is [How can I transform rows into repeated column based data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674964/how-can-i-transform-rows-into-repeated-column-based-data/11676403#11676403).

Answer (score 3):

How about a real answer instead of a link?

1. Highlight the two rows to pivot.
2. Copy
3. Find open row
4. `Paste Special` -> `Transpose`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain a "dynamic" link between your source and target data, so whenever your source data changes, your target also does it automatically, you need formulas.
In that case, you can use Item 7 from [Excel: Formulas for converting data among column / row / matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800820/excel-formulas-for-converting-data-among-column-row-matrix/20800915#20800915) :

To get in `matrix_data3` the transpose of `matrix_data2`, one only needs to use `matrix_data2_top_left` and `matrix_data3_top_left`, with the formula

```
=OFFSET(matrix_data2_top_left,COLUMN()-COLUMN(matrix_data3_top_left),ROW()-ROW(matrix_data3_top_left))
```

and copied to a suitable target range.

Note that `matrix_data2_top_left` and `matrix_data3_top_left` are convenient [Excel range names](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) for the upper left cells of the source and target ranges, respectively, and they can be replaced in the formula by their absolute references (e.g., `$B$1` and `$B$6`).
Also, `matrix_data2` and `matrix_data3` are Excel range names, but these ranges (either as names or absolute references) are not needed here.